# password_verify() can't verify when getting password from database

Tags: php, database, hash

It will work if i do this:

```
<?php
$password = 'abc123';
$hash = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
if(password_verify('abc123',$hash)){
    echo 'Yes';
}
else{
    echo 'no';
}
?>
```

But when I implement this code into my login formhandler the password_verify() method will always give me FALSE.
My codes are here:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sqlSelect = "SELECT Email, Password FROM UserDetail WHERE Email='$email'";
 $result = $conn->query($sqlSelect);
 if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $pass = $row['Password'];
    if(password_verify($password,$row['Password'])) {
        print "Welcome ".$row['Name'].". You have logged in";

    } else {
        echo "wrong passw";
        echo "$pass";
    }
 } else {
    echo "wrong email";
 }
```

It will always say wrong passw.
I have tested add the variables and they work correctly. Is that because password_hash and password_verify only works when they are used in the same php script?

Comment: What version of php do you have? http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Start by confirming that the password hash you get out of the database is the same that you put in. Perhaps the column is too small and the value gets truncated, or you're messing up the value by escaping it wrong or some such thing.

Comment: Make sure the database field is at least `varchar(60)`, even better would be `varchar(255)` to be future proof.